# python script not exiting after using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

so i just wrote a simple code with multiprocessing,Pool() and Queue() and when i execute it with this command it keeps open for ever

```
python3 m.py
```

i can see that 5 of my Cpu cores finish the job and cpu usage decrease to normal but steel its not closing and i have to press Ctrl + c to exit from it.

here is my code :

```
    from multiprocessing import Queue,Pool
    import csv,json
    from itertools import chain

    def worker(line):
     j_string = json.dumps(line)
     worker.output_q.put(j_string)

    def worker_init(output_q):
     worker.output_q = output_q

    f_open = open('khodro','rt')
    f_csv = csv.reader(f_open)

    output_q = Queue()

    pool = Pool(5,worker_init,[output_q])
    pool.imap(worker,chain(f_csv),1000)
    raise SystemExit()
```

Comment: are you using windows? you'd need to add `if __name__=="__main__"` before creating the pool.

Comment: im on ubuntu 16.04 , i add this but the script just get closed without doing any processing, why should we write this before creating pool?

Comment: did you paste the full script? `imap` is not blocking and the script you posted generated 5 processes but the parent process immediately terminates and also makes the subprocesses terminate. Either you have a `join()` at the end or you consume the elements by `for el in pool.imap`, but the script as you have pasted does not do what you describe

Comment: @hansaplast this is the hole script , i didn't continue coding since i have this problem, putting pool.close() and pool.join() doesn't solve the problem, the script just fill a queue which is output_q that i initialized into worker

Comment: how big is `khodro`?

Comment: it works fine when i past it in python interactive command

Comment: @hansaplast khodro is 100kb there is other files that are bigger than 100mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why exactly, but the problem lies in you filling the output queue with `worker.output_q.put(j_string)`. If you remove that line the script does terminate. If you print out the line it is printing you see that it hangs after processing the last line. I guess it's because you don't explicetly `close()` the output queue at the end. In fact you can't because in `worker` you don't know if it is the last line or not.

Good news is that what you're trying to achieve with the output queue is done by `imap` itself when you `return` in the function:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue,Pool
import csv,json
from itertools import chain

def worker(line):
    return json.dumps(line)

f_open = open('generated.json','rt')
f_csv = csv.reader(f_open)
pool = Pool(5)

for j_string in pool.imap(worker,f_csv,1000):
    print(j_string)
```

The `for` loop iterates over the queue which is filled by `imap`, so internally it is (AFAIK) the same as you're trying to achieve.

Since `imap` is not blocking you can start processing the outputs of `worker` before all workers ran through.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is correct but if you need queue based solution then use Manager Queue.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
mgr = Manager()
output_q = mgr.Queue()
```

I tested this on Python 3.6.8 it works.